# Show error message on empty input field then hide message when input field is populated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In my Vue.js app, I have an search input, at the moment if the search is empty it shows an error message which is fine, but I want to hide it when the user has started to add input into the search field. So far my component code is as follows, which shows the template and script areas.

```
<template>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">{{title}}</h1>
    <p class="lead">{{intro}}</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
    </p>
    <p v-for="(error, index ) in errors" :key="index">{{ error }}</p>
    <input
      class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search"
      aria-label="Search"
      v-model="search"
      required
    >

    <div class="loading" v-if="loading"></div>

    <table class="table table-sm table-light table-bordered" v-if="result.length">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="col-8">
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Artist</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(result, index) in result" :key="index">
          <td>{{result.collectionName}}</td>
          <td>{{result.artistName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button
      class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block mb-3"
      type="submit"
      v-on:click="getData"
      v-if="result.length < 1"
    >Get data</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Hero",
  props: {
    navLink: String
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      title: "Simple Search",
      intro: "This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style.",
      subintro:
        "It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out.",
      result: [],
      errors: [],
      search: "",
      loading: ""
    };
  },

  watch: {
    search: function(val) {
      if (!val) {
        this.result = [];
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getData: function() {
      this.loading = true;
      fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${this.search}&entity=album`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.result = data.results;
          this.loading = false;
          console.log(data);
        });
      if (this.search) return true;
      this.errors = [];
      if (!this.search) this.errors.push("Enter search field.");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Any idea's would be great, do I need to add it to the `v-if` statement or in the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You should watch `search` attribute, then update errors array if `search` is not entered:

```
methods: {
  getData: function() {
    this.loading = true;
    fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${this.search}&entity=album`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.result = data.results;
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
},
watch: {
  search: function(val) {
    if (!val) {
      this.result = [];
      this.errors = [];
      this.errors.push("Enter search field.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing the code to this, does not display the error message at all